# Laravel 4 : Embedding blade template tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have saved some template tags in database, i want to process them when they are fetched from database. For instance, i have included this file in content and saved it in DB. When i fetch it just prints out in plain text.

```
@include('frontend.map')
```

Is there any way to process it? I know .blade extension is required for the engine to parse but how do we deal when the template tags and variables are saved in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Blade wont support that.

What your asking is to allow Blades commands to be interpreted from supplied variables. It would actually be a massive security risk.

You'll need to have another solution that does not involve the use of Blade function calls inside your variables (database).

Perhaps have your view load a different template based upon the variable that you need?